# What's an angular lifecycle-hook need when changing sets in componentInstance property by service?

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, angular-material2, angular2-changedetection

I have a component that i send to MdDialog(Angular Material Dialog in my custom service.ts)

```
dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, config);
```

And when I change a public property of this component by componentInstance like that:

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.task = task;
```

Angular shows me an error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'dialog'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?

Full code of open-modal.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksPopupService {

constructor(
  private dialog: MdDialog,
  private router: Router,
  private tasksService: TasksService
) { }

public open(component: any, id?: string) {

if (id) {
  this.tasksService.find(id)
    .subscribe(task => {
      this.bindDialog(component, task);
    });
} else {
  this.bindDialog(component, new Task());  
  }
}

bindDialog(component, task: Task) {
  let dialogRef;
  let config = new MdDialogConfig();
  config.height = '80%';
  config.width = '70%';
  dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, config);
  dialogRef.componentInstance.task = task;
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { popup: null } }], { replaceUrl: true });
  });
  return dialogRef;
  }
}
```

But an error occured only if id is undefined (in ELSE block) I think it's because of **this.tasksService.find return Observable (async)**, and block ELSE is not async. But I'm not sure.

Comment: This will help you understand the error better [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Yeah, i found it. Thanks you for it. I followed to you in Medium!

Comment: that's great, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I has some confuse becouse error eccured in MdContainer of Angular Material.
If i get data from server it's need some time, but when i pass a new object it's occur fast and change detection is not finished if i understend right. 
Also, it's not parent/child component and lifecycle hooks maybe not works as we expect.
I found solution, but it's not right. Just fast solution.

```
if (id) {
  this.tasksService.find(id)
    .subscribe(task => {

      this.bindDialog(component, task);
    });
} else {
  Observable.of(new Task()).delay(300).subscribe(task => {
    this.bindDialog(component, task);
  });
}
```

I use delay for change detection has finished and error will not throw.